# Rails acts as taggable on, get all related objects that have a certain tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a **n-to-n** relation between `Foo` and `Bar` and Bar is a taggable object.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :xx
  has_many :bars, through: :xx
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :xx
  has_many :foos, through: :xx
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

I'm using the [acts as taggable on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem; I'd like to know if there is there a way to use `tagged_with` to *get all Foo objects that have a Bar object tagged with a certain tag*?

Example:

```
Foo.with_bar_tagged_with("input_search_tag")
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Foo>,...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved using the following:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).where("bars.id IN ?",Bar.tagged_with("input_search_tag")).uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

This is off the top of my head, but I'd expect something like.

```
def Foo.with_bar_tagged_with(tag)
  Bar.tagged_with(tag).collect{|x|x.bars}.flatten.uniq
end
```

Comment: I think it should be `x.foos` instead that `x.bars`. Your answer is ok but have some problem (too many query done). Check out my the answer I made (using Squeel)